# jQuery Validation plugin errorPlacement for checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I use jQuery Validation plugin to validate my form. My problem is the place of error message for checkbox. please see this image:

[image]

This is html part related to checkboxes + jQuery Validation:

```
<fieldset id = "q8"> <legend class="Q8"></legend>
<label> What are your favourite genres of movies?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content"> 

<style type="text/css">
 .checkbox-grid li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
}     
</style>

<ul class="checkbox-grid">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Action"><label for="checkgenre[]">Action</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Adventure"><label for="checkgenre[]">Adventure</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Comedy"><label for="checkgenre[]">Comedy</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Animation"><label for="checkgenre[]">Animation</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Drama"><label for="checkgenre[]">Drama</label></li> 
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Romance"><label for="checkgenre[]">Romance</label></li>
  //Continued the same for OTHER CHECKBOXES 

</div>
</fieldset>
 
  //html for other questions...

 <input class="mainForm" type="submit" name="continue" value="Save and Continue" />  

</form>

<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#form2').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    wrapper: "li",
   
    rules: {
       "q8[]": {
            required: true,
        },
       "q9[]": {
            required: true,
        },
        q10: {
            required: true,
        },
        q11: {
            required: true,
        },
        q12: {
            required: true,
        }

    },

      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

      if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
         error.insertBefore(element);
       } else {
         error.insertBefore(element);
         
    }
   }

 }); 
});
</script>
```

Could someone kindly help me if it is possible to fix this problem or showing the error
message (for all input types) right next to the question? (I mean exactly the same line as question, after * )??

Thanks

Comment: You should never put `<style></style>` tags within your `<body></body>` container.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I added a `class` to the `label` for your question in order to find that easier...

```
<label class="question">What are your favourite genres of movies?<span>*</span></label>
```

Then you simply need to practice your "DOM traversal" techniques.  Study the methods [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

- `$(element).parents('div')` finds the `div` container of your `element`.
- Then `.prev($('.question'))` gets you to the `.question` that is the first previous sibling of this `div`.

Put it all together and it inserts the error message right after the question.

```
error.insertAfter($(element).parents('div').prev($('.question')))
```

Within `errorPlacement`:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") {
        error.insertAfter($(element).parents('div').prev($('.question')));
    } else {
        // something else if it's not a checkbox
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvtd6y/**

Maybe you don't need the conditional, since that technique should work on all of your `input` types.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).parents('div').prev($('.question'))); 
}
```

Otherwise, if your HTML is different, then you can use the conditional with a slightly modified DOM traversal.

Comment: Wow! Worked well :) Thank you so much for your complete explanation :)